# How to group result into different column in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm still learning to use tableau and I'm having issue with visualize my data. Basically, I have  csv file contains QA report for a web-based and mobile app: a change-log for each version. For example, WebApp1 version 1.0: purchase page error > WebApp1 version 2.0: purchase page fixed.

I would like to display these data by listing each version and its QA change-log result. So far my tableau look like this: the version is still display in 1 column.

[image: csv data file and expected result]

Would it be possible to make the version separated into different column? I tried to group and combine different field, but so far no result. Am I missing something? This is the result I'm aiming for:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting Version on columns, then Platform on columns.

Leave Issue on rows. Then put Comment on the text card.

That should get you a lot closer, and you can try switching the position of the pills (Version and Platform) on the columns shelf to see what you prefer.

Comment: OMG text card solved my issue. Thank you so much.